# Bin folder for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, command-line, unix, shortcuts, binary-files

I'm trying to replicate a UNIX bin folder on my Windows 10 PC. I have created a folder located at "C:\bin" and added it to my PATH variable. However, I'm not really sure as how to implement it any further than this. I've tried adding shortcuts (lnk-files) to the folder but I can't get that to work.

My goal is to be able to write "python37" in the command prompt to run "C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe" and write "python38" to run "C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe".

Simply adding both directories to the PATH variable wouldn't work since both of the executables have the same name, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to create shortcuts and run them like in your original attempt.  What's not working?  But yes, you would have to name the shortcuts something unique in your bin folder.  You would need to include the `.lnk` extension when executing.

So, in your `C:\bin` folder and with it in your path create a shortcut to the Python32 exe, name it python37 and execute it by:

```
C:\somedir> python37.lnk
```

Alternatively, you could create a .bat file and run it.  For Python37 you could create `C:\bin\python37.bat` with this as the contents:

```
"C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe" %*
```

That should let you exclude the extension if you just want a clean `python37` command.

```
C:\somedir> python37
```

Comment: The bat solution was what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: Awesome, cheers!

Comment: "You would need to include the .lnk extension when executing.".. you can edit your environment to not require this.  Simply add .LNK to your PATHEXT variable.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Ah, good point.  I never use that variable so I never think about it...

Answer (score 1):

You can simply have both folders in the path and make a copy of your Python37 and 38 with those names. It wouldn't hurt anything to have it executed from python37.exe instead of python.exe.

Answer (score 0):

### I know this is an old one but my solution is one I made up in the NT4 days and STILL WORKS better than anything else I see here (IMHO) so I thought that I would share.

1. Create your C:\Bin folder.
2. Add it to your path.
3. While in the [environment variables dialog](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000002146), find an entry called `PATHEXT` under "System Variables".  Add `;.LNK` to the list.
4. When you drop links into this folder, edit the shortcut and remove all text from the "Start In" field and trim the name to whatever you want to type.  Keep the .lnk (of course) but you won't need to type it.
5. Drop the mic. <BOOM!>  You are done.

Lets say we dropped a [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/) shortcut in there and called it `NPP.lnk`.  You can now access notepad++ from anywhere to include the windows Run dialog and the command prompt and it will accept relative as well as full paths.

If you were in `C:\Windows` at the command prompt, `NPP system.ini` would work. `NPP C:\Windows\system.ini` would also work.  `NPP C:\Windows\system.ini` would also work from the windows run dialog.

Notes:

- There is a small security risk in allowing .LNK files to be executable. Think this through.. but OP is asking for it so..
- The reason the relative paths work is because we blanked the "Start In" field in the shortcut.
- Even though I am an engineer, my path is small.  I use this method to get MANY things out of my path.  It doesn't work for everything.. but it seems to work for most things.
- This even works to make custom wrappers around apps (as in call a script that calls the thing instead) without seeming odd to use.
- I have 30 or so things in this folder.  Even a link that launches zoom straight into standup meetings.  I type [Win]+[R] `standup` [Enter].

I know I am supposed to use fancy buttons for keyboard text stuff.  Please someone comment and tell me how to do that and I will update my post.  THANKS! :)

Answer (score -1):

Windows Environmental Variables are what you're looking for, you need to add a "bin" folder to your PATH inside Environmental Variables.

Comment: Welcome to SU. I'm a bit confused... the OP has already added `C:\bin` to their `%PATH%`. The issue is they have 2 executables with the same name, so they can't simply add both paths  to `%PATH%`. So how exactly does this help them resolve the problem with the executable names?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1176895)